# How to translate an array of values from DB

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an array of values that get from DB:

```
$repairs = DB::table('repair_parts')->orderBy('repair', 'asc')
                        ->where('status_id', '1')->distinct()->lists('repair', 'id');
```

I want to ttranslate those values in another lang. To display in the view:

```
{{ Form::select('repair', $repairs, isset($v->repair_id) ? $v->repair_id : '', array( 
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'id'=>'repair_field',
                'placeholder' => Lang::get('messages.repair'))) 
 }}
```

the problem is that I can't translate them with Lang::get('repair'.$repairs). Is there any other way to do it?

**EDIT**

```
array(13) { [22]=> string(2) "dd" [23]=> string(3) "fff" [21]=> string(4) "Test" [5]=> string(4) "test" [13]=> string(4) "test" [7]=> string(5) "test3" [14]=> string(5) "test4" [15]=> string(5) "test6" [16]=> string(5) "test6" [18]=> string(5) "test6" [19]=> string(5) "test6" [17]=> string(5) "test6" [20]=> string(5) "Tires" }
```

Comment: How do you have them stored in the `lang/repair.php` ?

Comment: I have stored all values from db like 'db_value'=>'translation' but the problem is that they cant be translatet as they are displayed in dropdown as an array

Comment: Well then, is the `Lang::get('repair.' . $repair[0]);` returning one translated string?

Comment: this shows Undefined offset: 0

Comment: @delmadord just edited the question with the array printed. Any idea?

Comment: @user3660185 the array is numerically keyed, not `value => translation`, unless you meant to be calling integers with the lang class.

Comment: @David Barker so what solution do you give me ?

Comment: @user3660185 Read the docs on localisation (http://laravel.com/docs/localization) and structure your lang array properly?

Comment: @David Barker all other langs are working just lists('repair', 'id') complicates things. If you know how to translate values from lists() I would be grateful to you.

Comment: There is no current way to use lists unfortunately. You will have to either extend the translator core class or write your own code that does it :(

Comment: @David Barker without using lists I just get all id but the problem is that when  foreach ($repairs as $r) 
It repeates the dropdown. I want only one dropdown and have problems in reading all array values in one

Answer (score 1):

Solved. What I did was append to the values of the array

```
array_walk($repairs, function(&$value, $key) { $value = Lang::get('repair.'.$value); });
```

and I got translated values.